# calcular descuento y precio con descuento PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Hola a todos,el problema es el siuiente:**

Estoy desarrollando una tienda en linea (ya esta completa),pero le estoy agregando un sistema de cupones de descuento,los cupones (ya estan terminados desde el admin y ligados a un producto),en la pagina de productos muestro una tabla con los productos y tambien se muestran los productos que tienen descuento aparte de los que no,los productos que tienen descuento hay de 2 tipos (dcto % y dcto por monto fijo).los de monto fijo andan bien pero los de % no.

**Principal Problema:**

1. La tienda tiene un panel de control desde donde se actualiza el valor del dolar manualmente
2. Este valor del dolar esta en casi todas las tablas de la BD,incluidas las que intervienen en los productos y cupones
3. siempre se agrega un valor en $COP peso colombiano pero al momento de insertar en la BD se inserta en US dolares,entonces este valor en casi todos los casos posibles se actualiza en todas las tablas de la BD por cada query realizada y tambien se obtiene este valor de la tabla_ajustes
4. por lo anterior necesito calcular el descuento y el precio final del producto en la pagina de cupones(ya esta realizado para monto_fijo y valor_porcentual %) y en la pagina de productos(ya esta realizado para monto_fijo - tipo_cupon = falta valor_porcentual %)
5. entonces seun lo que yo menciono en el punto 4 estan las condiciones que validan si el tipo_cupon es monto_fijo o dcto_porcentual % en la pagina productos para los cuales si tienen cupon activo relacionado

**Necesito por favor saber:** que error estoy cometiendo o cual es la forma correcta que debo emplear para mostrar todo correctamente.(ya le he dado vueltas y aun nada con el tipo de cupon_porcentual)... ya abajo explico porque no he podido y porque es confuso

1. porque uso la funcion `number_format($row['p_current_price'])` y `number_format((float)$row['p_current_price'])` .. tambien esta otra `number_format($FinalPriceValueUS, 2, '.', '')`
2. tengo toda mi tienda en linea

> mostrando al mismo tiempo los valores en dolares y su respectiva
> conversion equivalente en pesos colombianos

3. he probado en guardar las conversiones en variables aparte para separar todos los distintos procesos y asi tener mas ordenado el codigo

**Resultado final:** el unico producto que por el momento posee tipo_cupon = cupon_porcentaje es el producto (uniforme construccion),el cual tiene un valor de $3.89USD y en COP $18.272 pesos colombianos,el DTCO debe ser de $3.753 COP ($0.81 US DOLLAR) y el precio final del producto con el DCTO ya aplicado debe resultar en $14.519 COP ($3.14 US DOLLAR).

**Ayuda:** no se que estoy colocando mal,si el orden es incorrecto,se vuelve confuso para mi pero los valores no los muestra como explico se supone deberian de quedar,aradezco su colaboracion

En adelante adjunto el codigo PHP correspondiente:

```
<!-- language: lang-php-->
<?php 
if($row['id_coupon'] == $row1['id_coupon']){
if($row['id_coupon'] <> '0'){
echo "<p style='text-align:center;'>" . "Yes" . "</p>" . "<hr style='margin-top:0px;border-top:2px solid #3335;'>";
// SI CALCULAMOS EL DESCUENTO DE CUPONES DE TIPO
// (%) SOBRE EL VALOR DEL PRODUCTO Y LUEGO 
// RESTAMOS ESE DCTO.. NO OLVIDAR DIVIDIR POR 100
if($row1['coupon_type'] == 'percent_value'){
// DISCOUNTED VALUE IN US DOLLAR...
// (COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT)
$DiscountedValueUS = number_format((float)$row1['coupon_discount'], 2, '.', '');
// FINAL PRICE WITH DISCOUNT APPLIED IN 
// US DOLLAR...
// (COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT)
$FinalPriceValueUS = number_format((float)$row['p_current_price'], 2, '.', '') - $DiscountedValueUS / 100;

// DISCOUNTED VALUE IN COLOMBIAN PESO...
/* ***  PARA CONVERTIR DE DOLAR A PESO COLOMBIANO SE MULTIPLICA POR EL VALOR DEL DOLAR *** */
                                                          
//
$CurrentPriceConvertToPesos = 
                                                          number_format($row['p_current_price']) * $row['ValorDolarUS'];
                                                          
$DiscountConvertToPesos = number_format($row1['coupon_discount']) * $row['ValorDolarUS'];
//
                                                          
// (COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT)
$DiscountedValueCOP = number_format($CurrentPriceConvertToPesos) * $DiscountConvertToPesos;
                                                          
// FINAL PRICE WITH DISCOUNT APPLIED IN 
// COLOMBIAN PESO...
// (COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT)
$FinalPriceValueCOP = $CurrentPriceConvertToPesos - $DiscountedValueCOP / 100; 
                                                          
// FINAL PRICE MESSAGE FOR US DOLLAR...
// (COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT)
echo "Final Price Of Product" . "<br>" . "With Discount Applied: " . "<br><br>" . "$" . number_format($FinalPriceValueUS, 2, '.', '') . "<span> <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-usa'> </i> USA</span>" . "<br><br>";
                                                          
// FINAL PRICE MESSAGE FOR COLOMBIAN PESO...
// (COUPON_TYPE = PERCENT_AMOUNT)
echo "Final Price Of Product" . "<br>" . "With Discount Applied: " . "<br><br>" . "$" . number_format($FinalPriceValueCOP) . "<span> <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-col'> </i> COP</span>" . "<br><br>";
                                                          
}elseif($row1['coupon_type'] == 'fix_amount'){
// DISCOUNTED VALUE IN US DOLLAR...
// (COUPON_TYPE = FIX_VALUE)
$DiscountedValueUS = number_format((float)$row1['coupon_discount'], 2, '.', '');
// FINAL PRICE WITH DISCOUNT APPLIED IN 
// US DOLLAR...
// (COUPON_TYPE = FIX_VALUE)
$FinalPriceValueUS = number_format((float)$row['p_current_price'], 2, '.', '') - $DiscountedValueUS;
// DISCOUNTED VALUE IN COLOMBIAN PESO...
/* ***  PARA CONVERTIR DE DOLAR A PESO COLOMBIANO SE MULTIPLICA POR EL VALOR DEL DOLAR *** */
// (COUPON_TYPE = FIX_VALUE)
                                                          
//
$DiscountConvertToPesos = number_format($row1['coupon_discount']) * $row['ValorDolarUS'];
                                                          
$CurrentPriceConvertToPesos = number_format($row['p_current_price']) * $row['ValorDolarUS'];
//
                                                          
$DiscountedValueCOP = $DiscountConvertToPesos;            
// FINAL PRICE WITH DISCOUNT APPLIED IN 
// COLOMBIAN PESO...
// (COUPON_TYPE = FIX_VALUE)
$FinalPriceValueCOP = $CurrentPriceConvertToPesos - $DiscountedValueCOP;
                                                          
// FINAL PRICE MESSAGE FOR US DOLLAR...
// (COUPON_TYPE = FIX_VALUE)
echo "Final Price Of Product" . "<br>" . "With Discount Applied: " . "<br><br>" . "$" . number_format($FinalPriceValueUS, 2, '.', '') . "<span> <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-usa'> </i> USA</span>" . "<br><br>";
                                                          
// FINAL PRICE MESSAGE FOR COLOMBIAN PESO...
// (COUPON_TYPE = FIX_VALUE)
echo "Final Price Of Product" . "<br>" . "With Discount Applied: " . "<br><br>" . "$" . number_format($FinalPriceValueCOP) . "<span> <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-col'> </i> COP</span>" . "<br><br>";
                                                          
}
 
}
}else{
// SI NO CUMPLE LA CONDICIONAL DE ARRIBA ENTONCES
// TIENE id_coupon = '0', ENTONCES ES INVALIDO 
echo 'No';
}
?>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien cual es exactamente tu problema, pero para calcular el descuento porcentual de un producto puedes utilizar una función:

```
function percentageDiscount($amount, $discount){
    $discountPerCent = $discount / 100;
    return $amount * (1 - $discountPerCent);
}
```

Con esta función, si introduces:

```
percentageDiscount(100, 20) // Devuelve 80, que es el precio menos el 20%
```

Allá donde quieras descontar porcentualmente, aplicas la función y listo.
Espero que te sirva.
P.D.
Un consejo, simplifica tu código al máximo, las cosas simples son mucho más fáciles de leer y depurar

Answer (score 0):

el problema está en estas dos lineas:

```
$FinalPriceValueUS = number_format((float)$row['p_current_price'], 2, '.', '') - $DiscountedValueUS / 100;
$FinalPriceValueCOP = $CurrentPriceConvertToPesos - $DiscountedValueCOP / 100;
```

No llego a entender el porque de dos lineas aplicando el descuento (son para las distintas monedas?) pero ambas tiene un sutil error, debes multiplicar el precio por el descuento y dividirlo por 100, quedaría así:

```
$FinalPriceValueUS = number_format((float)$row['p_current_price'], 2, '.', '') * $DiscountedValueUS / 100;
$FinalPriceValueCOP = $CurrentPriceConvertToPesos * $DiscountedValueCOP / 100;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.